# How to Remove Date Format SAS

Tags: sas

I have a column of dates with the DATE9. format applied. How can I remove that format so it just shows the SAS date number. For example, I have the date 01JUN2021 but I want it as 22432.

Comment: The value already is 22,432.  The format just determines how it is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the format statement but don't apply a format.
This essentially removes a format. Alternatively you could apply a numeric format such as 8. or best12.

```
format variableName;
```